# SonarQube says "Not covered by tests" for most of lines

Tags: qt, sonarqube, qt5, code-coverage

I'm evaluating SonarQube Developer for our development team, and facing most of the lines are tagged as "Not covered by tests".

I suppose "not covered" means "not checked or not tested". Am I guess right?

Please let me know the exact meaning of "not covered" and why this happens.

Below are the background info. of this evaluation.

- SonarQube 7.3 (BuildWrapper and SonarScanner for Windows)
- C/C++ Project using Qt 5.9

Screenshot of SonarQube Console

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SonarQube reads code coverage reports and marks which lines have been tested (covered by tests). `not covered` means that those lines are not included in the code coverage reports. There are two options, your tests:

1. don't check the code from the screen
2. check the code from the screen, but the code coverage report:

   - didn't include data of these tests
   - has not been generated and uploaded to the server

Documentation about [SonarQube Test Coverage & Execution](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/).

Comment: you mentioned - those lines are not included in the code coverage reports. why SonarQube did that and when SonarQube will cover these lines?. I am also facing same issue. what needs to be done to resolve?

Comment: SonarQube only displays coverage results produced by other tools. You have to use a coverage tool (like JaCoCo for Java), execute it and next performs SonarScanner analysis. If the lines are covered by tests, they will be marked as covered in SonarQube UI.